# Travel through Cambridge

Tags: public-transport, cambridge

I was wondering if the CITI busline in Cambridge and the Busway (e.g., B) work with the same daily ticket (£4).

Moreover, I would like to move from Currys PC world in Newmarket road to Ring Fort Road (near Orchard park). I have seen that there is a bus stop near orchard park through which you can take the busway B. Then, in front of Currys, there is a bus stop for CITI 3 that gets from city center. But:

- I cannot find the right point in which I can change between busway B and CITI 3
- it seems that in front of the "River lane" stop in front of Currys there is not another bus stop that goes back to the city center (although you walk a bit)

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

Get on Citi 3 towards town centre - get off at Four Lamps roundabout. Then walk 50yds further down Short Street (ie turn left), and on right hand side is Busway stop - get on a B service (any) for Orchard Pk.

Answer (score 1):

The Stagecoach Dayrider (now £4.50) covers all Stagecoach services in the city area ([see map](https://tiscon-maps-stagecoachbus.s3.amazonaws.com/ZoneMaps/East/EST-Cambridge-Megarider-Aug17.pdf)). This includes all the Busway, Park & Ride, and Citi services. One exception is the U, which is operated by Whippet instead.

Most routes are likely to pass through the city centre, which is densely packed with bus stops along and around Drummer Street, Emmanuel Street, and St Andrew's Street. Another major bus junction is at Station Place.